# Does universal selector (*) in combination with :last-child work in all mobile browsers?

Tags: css, pseudo-class, universal, css-selectors

I have a div container which may contain different kinds of child elements:

```
<div id="my-container">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
    <div>...</div>
    <blockquote>...</blockquote>
    ...
</div>
```

I want to select the last element in my container and apply certain styles to it. But I don't know if the last element is a p, a div, or whatever. This is how I would do that:

```
#my-container > *:last-child {
    /* my styles */
}
```

Will this work in all mobile browsers?
(In this case, I don't care about desktop browsers.)

Thanks a lot!
Karl

Comment: http://caniuse.com/css-sel3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prepending the universal selector is unnecessary in this case, since not specifying a selector before `:last-child` will still allow it to target any element that is a last-child within a parent.

The `:last-child` pseudo-class is also well supported among mobile browsers according to [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/css-sel3).

Instead just use:

```css
#my-container > :last-child {
    /* my styles */
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/utEUw/4/